# Race condition in Amplify.Hub signIn handler when using oath

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

Example code:

```js
Hub.listen('auth', event => {
  const { event: type, data } = event.payload;

  if (type === 'signIn') {
    const session = data.signInUserSession;
    console.log('SESSION', data.signInUserSession);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('SESSION', data.signInUserSession);
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

When using oath, after the provider redirects to my app, the Hub fires a `signIn` event. However, the `signInUserSession` property is `null` when the event is fired, but gets a value some time later (within 100 ms). This does not seem to occur when using `Auth.signIn(email, password)` directly; `signInUserSession` is populated when the event is fired.

What is happening here, and how can I get around it? Currently, I have an explicit delay in the code, which is a terrible hack.

Comment: What is the version you are using? I tried to reproduce this in the app I am using not successful

Comment: You can use promise in javascript also.

Comment: Where or how are you listening this event, is the code part of a component or any singleton class?

Comment: I'm using redux-saga, and using `Hub.listen` to power an event channel. However, I also tried running the above example code directly from a saga, and had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the old way of JavaScript for waiting for value to be populated is useful to ensure that code does not fail even if the it takes longer than expected in populating the value.

Here is a sample code that I normally use when no other options are available.

```
waitForValue(){
    if(myVar!= null && typeof myVar !== "undefined"){
        //value exists, do what you want
        console.log(myVar)
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(() => {this.waitForValue()}, 100);
    }
}
```

You can refactor this sample code as per your need.

Alternatively, AWS Amplify also have other ways to get current logged in user session. e.g. `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` and `Auth.currentSession()` return promise. They can be used like this

```
private async getUser(){
    let user = null;
    try {
      user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      //console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
      //console.log(err);
    }
    //return user;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not used to aws amplify - just read some github and so far i can see we will need info about your [`userPool`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/44c4d332f0737efc17a613153f84055cd72f52e8/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L318) implementation - i guess some weird callback issue

But for a workaround you can proxy the reference:

```js
const event = {type: "signIn", data: {signInProperty: "null"}}

setTimeout(()=>event.data.signInProperty = "{Stack: Overflow}", 1000)

// mock events
function emit(type, args){
  console.log(type, args)
}

//initialize
let watchedValue = event.data.signInProperty
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = event.data.signInProperty 
// protect reference
Object.defineProperty(event.data, "signInProperty", {
    set(newValue){
      watchedValue = newValue
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = newValue
      emit("event:signInCompleted", event.data)
    },
    get(){
      return watchedValue
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```